# Mocha chai request time out exceed on res.json

Tags: json, express, mocha.js, response, chai

I'm using chai agent to test a loggin, but i'm getting

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test

it('POST /api/v1/account/me status 500', function(done) {
  var agent = chai.request.agent(server);
    agent.post('/api/v1/account/login')
        .send({_email: 'test@test.com', _password: 'testtest'})
        .then(function(res){
        agent.get('/api/v1/account/logout')
            .then(function(res2){
                agent.get('/api/v1/account/me')
                    .then(function(res3){
                        res2.should.have.status(500);
                        done();
                    });
        });
    });
});
```

In my "/api/v1/account/me", i have:

```
router.get('/me', auth.isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.json(new Response({error:false, results: req.session.user}))
});
```

And my isAuthenticated:

```
isAuthenticated: function (req, res, next) {

    var sess = req.session;
    if(sess.user)
        return next();

    res.status(500).json(new Response({error:true})).end();
    return;
}
```

The problem is that

```
res.status(500).json(new Response({error:true})).end();
```

never returns 500. If i change status(500) with status(200), everything works fine (not the test, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems in the code.

1. `.then` accept two callback parameters: the first one handles success response (200 OK), the second one handles failed response (404, 500 etc.). Thus, you need to put the assertion code inside the second callback. Sample code is:

   ```
   agent.get('/api/v1/account/me')
       .then(function(res3) {
           // assertion statements when response is successful.
       }, function(res4) {
           // assertion statements when response is failed.
           res4.should.have.status(500);
       });
   ```
2. Don't use `done`. When chai assertion statement failed (`res4.should.have.status(500)`), it will throw an `AssertionError`, which means the `done` callback would never be invoked -- eventually, leads to "Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded.". Instead, just `return` the agent invokation result and it's good to go:

   ```
   var agent = chai.request.agent(server);
   return agent.post('/api/v1/account/login')
               ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add inside the Describe, or before the **it**. And you should use Async library to chain those calls.

```
describe('',function(){
    this.timeout(15000);
    it('', function(done){
        Async.series([], function(cb){
            function(cb){
                cb();
            },
            function(cb){
                cb();
            }
        }, function(err){
            done();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't think this is the problem. Also, i want to add that .then() is executed when response is sent. So it works fine with asynchronous function.